# Python self contained web application and server?

Tags: python, deployment

What is a good and easy way to distribute a web application and server bundled together, python way?

So I can say to a user "Here take this tar/whatever, unpack it and run blahblah.py" and blahblah.py will run a http/wsgi server and serve my application?

Im looking for a stable production-ready multi-threaded wsgi-server with which I can bundle my app, without the need for nginx or other "frontends" or having to deal with any configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) can act as a WSGI container.

Comment: To clarify. The CherryPy framework contains a WSGI server that can be used separately. You do not have to use the whole of CherryPy framework.

Comment: @Graham would it be possible to take out the multithreaded WSGI server from CherryPy?

Comment: Isn't that what I said could be done when said 'that can be used separately'? The CherryPy download page even has a direct link to how you can download raw source. Although unfortunately they are broken at the moment as they haven't updated the links after thet restructured their repository. http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyDownload#StandaloneWSGIserver

Comment: So, what you need to do is just browse the repo and you will end up at http://www.cherrypy.org/browser/tags/cherrypy-3.2.1/cherrypy/wsgiserver Look at Py2 or Py3 version and then look at raw text. Eg http://www.cherrypy.org/browser/tags/cherrypy-3.2.1/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py?format=txt Save as from browser and go for it.

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this discussion on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/fp0hp/what_webserver_to_bundle_with_python_application/) informative.

Answer (score 0):

`cherrypy` is the easiest one to use, `django` is feature rich and `tornado` is more advanced with asynchrounous web server(in my opinion it is better than multithreaded web server).
For what you want, django is best suitable for you IMO.

Comment: also django is not really a web server, sure its development server is fine, but not for production I think. why do you think async web server is better than multithreaded?